# Remove all versions of Java except two

Tags: java

I need a programmatic way of removing all versions of Java except two (two that I define).

In our environment we have about 50 different versions of java and a lot of clients (Windows 7 Pro) have multiple versions so the possibilities are endless.

One option i have is to write uninstall scripts for every version. This, I feel, isnt good practice and will require me to update and deploy a new version every time a new version of Java is released (daily it seems like).

I can't figure out another way to this, one idea was to write a loop that goes through HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall and removes all the unwanted versions.

I'm not stuck on one programming language. I am most comfortable with .bat and .ps1 but .vbs could be used if required...

Any ideas or thoughts?

Comment: What about looping through and removing the jre and jdk directories that match the pattern of the versions you don't want?

Comment: There's a tool called [JavaRa](https://singularlabs.com/software/javara/) - the developers claim that it's able to find and remove all currently installed JRE packages. I've never tried it so cannot say anything about how good it is.

Comment: @JamesWierzba - i dont want to have to update this everytime a new Java release comes out....

Comment: @AlexanderObersht, the JavaRA doesnt support silent uninstalls. I guess I forgot to mention that part is a requirement.

Comment: That's why I recommended a pattern, you could come up with a pattern that matches all versions less than 1.7.x.x for example. And remove accordingly. Look into regex